# How to insert a consistent vertical space after tikzpicture environments globally

Tags: tikz-pgf, vspace

I want to know how can I add a global macro in the preamble that sets a vertical space after each tikzpicture in the document, instead of explicitly repeating the `\vspace` command.

Comment: a tikz picture is a box, it has no spacing added, it is positioned in the same was as an `X` Any space you need to alter is added by whatever environment you a using around the tikz. It is always best to show a test  doument

Comment: Why do you want this? What's your problem? You could just do `\tikzset{every picture/.append style={execute at end picture={\path[reset cm] ([yshift=-<space>]current bounding box.south);}}}`. But this applies to *all* TikZ pictures, even those by other packages that just use TikZ for something.

Comment: I'm just trying some features of tikz in a document that is filled with tikzpicture envs only, and I wondered how can I set those envs apart in the document by adding some vertical space after -outside- each environment. The space I'm after isn't within the bounding box of the envs, but rather after them in the document to get rid of multiple \vspace cmds in the code.

Comment: If you only use real `tikzpicture` environments (no `\tikz` and no `\tikzpicture … \endtikzpicture` you can try `\AfterEndEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\vspace{<space>}}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's what I meant, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you may not want to change *every* tikzpicture in your document. Perhaps you can just define a new environment with your vertical space built in. That way it won't effect other packages that use Ti*k*Z and you can still make a standard tikzpicture if you need to (for example, an inline picture).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{mytikz}{\begin{tikzpicture}}{\end{tikzpicture}\vspace{1cm}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\tikz{\draw(0,0)node[fill]{}--(1,0)node[fill]{};}

\begin{mytikz}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{mytikz}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. This is also a good approach.